# Whats the difference between close and dispose in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I usually use below code, should it be right ?

```
 using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, myConn))
         {
             myConn.Open();
             rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         // TO DO .
     }
```

Which one is prefer? Please tell me the difference between them. In my opinion: when Pooling is false both close and dispose will shut down the connection. When Pooling is true close won't shut down the collection ,but dispose would.

Comment: _"shut down the collection"_ ?? You mean the connection. If pooling is enabled `Close` will not close the physical connection but just tell the pool that this connection is ready to be used. You should prefer the `using`-statement on everything that implements `IDisposable` anyway. `connection.Dispose` will call `connection.Close` implicitly.

Comment: Thanks dude,i got it

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Dispose()` on a `SqlConnection`, internally, it calls `Close()`, too.

There is no worry - you are free to use `Close()` manually, or just let `Dispose()` do it for you.

Comment: Thanks , i will test it by sql profiler.